# Populating two rows for a specific condition using SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SK        |    Code       |   SIG_Code    | ID
----        -----------      ----------     ----                    
1              A             S               1
1              B             S               2
1              C             M               3
2              A             B               4
3              A             S               5
4              A             B               6
4              B             B               7
```

Considering the above table, I want records that are having both 'A' and 'B' as their Code. I tried writing a query like this, SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Code= 'A' and Code= 'B'. But this doesn't seem to work. Using IN condition is also not giving me the desired output. Can someone help me in building up this query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select sk
from t
where code in ('A', 'B')
group by sk
having count(*) = 2;
```

This assumes no duplicates.  If duplicates are allowed, then use `count(distinct code) = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function as follows to fetch the entire record:

```
select * from
(
 select t.*,
        count(distinct code) over (partition by sk) as cnt
   from yout_table t
  where code in ('A', 'B')
) 
where cnt = 2
```

Above query will return 2 records for sk=1 (having code as A and B) and 2 records for sk=4

If you want all records for id which contains A and B both (3 records for sk = 1) then you can use the following code:

```
select * from
(
 select t.*,
        count(distinct case when code in ('A', 'B') then code end) 
               over (partition by sk) as cnt
   from yout_table t
) 
where cnt = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

i) Try using subquery

```
select* from #table a
where code in( 'A', 'B')
and SIG_Code in (select SIG_Code from #table b where code in ('B') and a.sk=b.sk)
```

ii) Try this below query using case and count fuctionality.

```
select sk, code, SIG_Code,ID from
(
 select t.*,
        count(case when code = 'b' then 'a' end) over (partition by sk) as cnt
   from #table t
  where code in ('A', 'B')
) a
where cnt = 1
```